# reposition objects created at the origin to follow a direction of a vector

Tags: three.js

[link to the jsfiddle of this question](http://jsfiddle.net/yeehawjared/gnpddmv6/1/)

How can I reposition objects created at the origin to follow a direction of a vector?

My fiddle shows a sphere with evenly distributed sprites.  I then create a disc (circle) of evenly distributed sprites.  My goal is to position the disc outside the sphere, matching the direction generated from origin > sphere object.

I believe my problem stems from the fact that I create the disc sprites at the origin, then try to reposition later by using `translateOnAxis`.

pertinent code.
`disc_objects` contains a few sprites;
`direction` is a `THREE.Vector3` with direction from origin > point on a sphere.  I need help aligning the disc_objects to that direction.

```
for (var i = 0, l = disc_objects.length; i < l; i++) {
    // Vogel's method of Fermat's spiral (Phyllotaxis)
    // http://blog.marmakoide.org/?p=1

    var theta = i * golden_angle;
    var r = Math.sqrt(i) / Math.sqrt(l);

    // all points are created around origin
    disc_objects[i].position.x = r * Math.cos(theta);
    disc_objects[i].position.y = r * Math.sin(theta);
    disc_objects[i].position.multiplyScalar(distance);

    // translate the arranged disc points to the random_point
    // adds disc twice as far away as ranom_point on sphere
    disc_objects[i].translateOnAxis(direction, distance * 2);  
    scene.add(disc_objects[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok figured it out.  I didn't realize you could create Object3D objects as parents, then add children.  All children have their origin relative to the parents.

```
parent = new THREE.Object3D();
parent.position.add(direction.clone().multiplyScalar(distance * 2));
parent.lookAt(vector);
scene.add(parent);
```

now when I add the disc points, they are relative to the parent, correctly "looking at" the origin.

Comment: its always great to have others provide input, thanks for the example.  I like your increase in number of sprites, Phyllotaxis looks so neat.